# Validations using regular Expressions

Tags: android, regex

Can someone point me on using Regular Expressions in android (Patterns and Matchers to be specific)

```
String pass_pattern  = "^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{4,10})$";
b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {    
            chek = et1.getText().toString();
            if(chek.equals(""))
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password",1000).show();
            }

            if(chek.matches(pass_pattern)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Valid pAssword",1000).show();
            }else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "InvalidpAssword",1000).show();}

        }
    });
```

this is my code currently, i wanna check if the user has entered atleast one small letter and atleast one capital letter and a number and the length should be 4-10 char's.

If i do this via .matches() it only compares only one of the condition in the above said string.

Comment: Yet another password validator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String pass_pattern  = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[^\\W_]{4,10}$";
```

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )  getting that

Comment: @sup: I have forgotten the double escape of java

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without using regexp:

```
boolean lowerCase = false;
boolean upperCase = false;
boolean digit = false;
int length = password.length();
for (char c : password.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        upperCase = true;
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
        lowerCase = true;
    if (Character.isDigit(c))
        digit = true;
    if (lowerCase && upperCase && digit)
        break;
}
```